# Python cx_Oracle bind variables

Tags: python, cx-oracle, bind-variables

I am a Python newbie, I am having troubles in the use of bind variables. If I execute the code below everything works fine.

```
bind= {"var" : "ciao"}
sql = "select * from sometable where somefield = :bind"
cur.prepare(sql)
cur.execute(sql,bind)
```

Instead if I add another bind variable I obtain an error.

```
bind= {"var" : "ciao"}
sql = "select * from sometable where somefield = :bind and otherfield = :bind"
cur.prepare(sql)
cur.execute(sql,(bind,bind))

cur.execute(sql,(bind,bind))
Oracle.NotSupportedError: Variable_TypeByValue(): unhandled data
```

I have solved it with

```
cur.execute(sql,(bind["var"],bind["var"]))
```

but I can't understand why the previous command was not ok.

Which is the correct way to use bind variables? I am using cx_Oracle.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You are misusing the binding.

There are three different ways of binding variables with cx_Oracle as one can [see here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/prez-python-queries-101587.html) :

1) by passing a tuple to a SQL statement with **numbered variables** :

```
sql = "select * from sometable where somefield = :1 and otherfield = :2"
cur.execute(sql, (aValue, anotherValue))
```

2) By passing keyword arguments to a SQL statement **with named variables** :

```
sql = "select * from sometable where somefield = :myField and otherfield = :anotherOne"
cur.execute(sql, myField=aValue, anotherOne=anotherValue)
```

3) By passing a dictionary to a SQL statement **with named variables** :

```
sql = "select * from sometable where somefield = :myField and otherfield = :anotherOne"
cur.execute(sql, {"myField":aValue, "anotherOne":anotherValue})
```

---

### Remarks

**Why does your code work then ?**

Let's try to understand what happens here :

```
bind= {"var" : "ciao"}
sql = "select * from sometable where somefield = :bind and otherfield = :bind"
cur.execute(sql,(bind["var"], bind["var"]))
```

Oracle will understand that it expects one variable. This is a named variable, linked by name `bind`. You should then give a parameter as a named parameter like this :

```
cur.execute(sql, bind="ciao")
```

Or using a dictionary, like that :

```
cur.execute(sql, {bind:"ciao"})
```

However, as cx_Oracle receives a tuple instead, it fallbacks in a binding by number, as if your SQL statement was :

```
sql = "select * from sometable where somefield = :1 and otherfield = :2"
```

And as you are passing `bind['var']` twice, which is just the string `"ciao"`. It is mapping the two tuple items to the numbered variables :

```
cur.execute(sql, ("ciao", "ciao"))
```

That runs by chance but the code is very misleading.

**Tuple with a single value to bind**

Also note that the first option requires a tuple. But if you have a single value to bind, you can use this notation to create a tuple of a single value :

```
sql = "select * from sometable where somefield = :1"
cur.execute(sql, (aValue,))
```

[EDIT] : Thanks to @tyler-christian for mentioning that passing a dict was supported by cx_Oracle.

Comment: For me it was missing the trailing comma in a single-item tuple. D'oh!

Comment: @Rob, indeed : type((1,)) = <type 'tuple'>, but type((1)) = <type 'int'>

Comment: In the second and third example, is there a typo in the SQL statement (should `my_field` be `myField`) or does this not matter at all?

Answer (score 5):

@ffarquest says that using a dictionary isn't supported by cx_Oracle but it is in fact, @giovanni-de-ciantis was just using it incorrectly.

---

```
named_params = {'dept_id':50, 'sal':1000}
query1 = cursor.execute(
    'SELECT * FROM employees WHERE department_id=:dept_id AND salary>:sal',
    named_params
)
```

OR

```
query2 = cursor.execute(
    'SELECT * FROM employees WHERE department_id=:dept_id AND salary>:sal',
    dept_id=50,
    sal=1000
)
```

---

In the given example, I believe the second reference to `:bind` would need to be replaced with something different because it isn't being done in sequential order. Also, renamed the variable `bind` to get rid of confusion.

```
bind_dict = {bind:"var" : diff:"ciao"}
sql = "select * from sometable where somefield=:bind and otherfield=:diff"
cur.prepare(sql)
cur.execute(sql, bind_dict )
```

---

This article is from 2007 showing that you can use a dictionary:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/prez-python-queries-101587.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the fact that using a dictionary is actually possible. My answer has been updated accordingly.