# TypeError: descriptor 'replace' requires a 'str' object but received a 'NoneType '

Tags: python, oracle, pandas, numpy

I am trying to replace the value '\x1c' with a space (" ") in a list of tuples queried directly from a remote oracle database using python. I get this error:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'replace' requires a 'str' object but received a 'NoneType '
```

Below is the code that  I am using, the last line of code from which the error comes:

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("WELCOME", "welcome", "(ABC)")
cursor = connection.cursor()
querystring = "select CUST_OR_CARD_ID,MESG from tbaadm.rtt where 
SYSTEM_DATE_TIME >= '01/JAN/18' and dcc_id='SPR'"
cursor.execute(querystring)
col=cursor.fetchall()

col = [tuple(map(lambda i: str.replace(i, "\x1c"," "), tup)) for tup in col]
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the actual datatype of the tuple elements? The intention to replace '\x1c' rather sounds like byte objects that might need to be decoded.

Comment: I am curious, how working my solution? Also if need `DataFrame` not better use [pd.read_sql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35781580) ?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are `None`s in tuples, so need filter it out

```
col = [tuple([str.replace(i, "\x1c"," ") for i in tup if pd.notnull(i)]) for tup in col]
```

Or `replace` non `None`s values only:

```
col=[tuple([str.replace(i, "\x1c"," ") if pd.notnull(i) else i for i in tup ]) for tup in col]
```

EDIT: Thank you @Paul Cornelius for suggestion use `string.replace`:

```
col = [tuple([i.replace("\x1c"," ") for i in tup if pd.notnull(i)]) for tup in col]

col = [tuple([i.replace("\x1c"," ") if pd.notnull(i) else i for i in tup ]) for tup in col]
```

Comment: What is the reason to use `str.replace(i, "\x1c"," ")` rather than `i.replace("\x1c"," ")`?

Comment: @PaulCornelius - I dont know, but agreem it looks better.