# How to convert SQL Oracle Database into a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, oracle, performance

I am trying to get a Oracle SQL database into python so I can aggregate/analyze the data. Pandas would be really useful for this task. But anytime I try to use my code, it just hangs and does not output anything. I am not sure its because I am using the cx oracle package and then using the pandas package?

```
import cx_Oracle as cxo
import pandas as pd 
dsn=cxo.makedsn(
    'host.net',
    '1111',
    service_name='servicename'
)
conn=cxo.connect(
    user='Username',
    password='password',
    dsn=dsn)
c=conn.cursor()
a=c.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE date like '%20%'")
conn.close
df=pd.DataFrame(a)
head(df)
```

However when I use the code below, it prints out the data I am looking for. I need to convert this data into a panda data frame,

```
for row in c: print(row)
conn.close()
```

I am very new to python so any help will be really appreciated!!

Comment: `.read_sql()` has a connection parameter. [CX_Oracle - import data from Oracle to Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781580/cx-oracle-import-data-from-oracle-to-pandas-dataframe) shows it being used with a `cx_Oracle` connection.

Comment: There are other answers with different methods like `pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())` - search with variations of `python pandas oracle sql `

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python-pandas and databases like mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065051/python-pandas-and-databases-like-mysql) - there is an answer there for `cx_Oracle`.

Comment: as wwii said - you can pass a query straight into the `read_sql` method - i.e `pd.read_sql("SELECT * ... ", con = conn)`

Comment: When I try to do that the program just hangs..

Comment: How much data (how many rows? how many columns?) are you trying to load into the dataframe? Also, how long does that query take to run natively in a database, say through Oracle SQL Developer? How big is the source table? Frankly `SELECT * FROM data WHERE date like '%20%'` looks like a query which will have suck-y performance on a big table, especially if `date` column is in fact defined with a DATE datatype.

Comment: It takes about 15 mins to run the query in an oracle sql developer, I am trying to write a script in python to lower the time. I will try to narrow down my query thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To convert a cx_Oracle cursor to dataframe you can use de following code.

```
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE date like '%20%'")
    from pandas import DataFrame
    df = DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
    df.columns = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]
    print("I got %d lines " % len(df))
```

Note I'm using the cursor as context manager. So it will be closed automatically on the end of the block.