# ORA-00942 when importing data from Oracle Database to Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, oracle

I try to import data from a oracle database to a pandas dataframe.

right Now i am using:

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
db_connection_string = '.../A1@server:port/servername'
con = cx_Oracle.connect(db_connection_string)
query = """SELECT* 
           FROM Salesdata"""
df = pd.read_sql(query, con=con)
```

and get the following error: `DatabaseError: ORA-00942: Table or view doesn't exist`

When I run a query to get the list of all tables:

```
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT table_name  FROM dba_tables")
for row in cur:
    print (row)
```

The output looks like this:

```
('A$',)
('A$BD',)
('Salesdata',)
```

What I am doing wrong? I used this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781580/cx-oracle-import-data-from-oracle-to-pandas-dataframe) to start.

If I use the comment to `print(query)`I get:

```
SELECT* 
           FROM Salesdata
```

Comment: Comment out your data frame df and print the query. print(query). Check what is the result. This would make us understand the issue

Answer (score 1):

Getting ORA-00942 when running SELECT can have 2 possible causes:

1. The table does not exist: here you should make sure the table name is prefixed by the table owner (schema name) as in `select * from owner_name.table_name`. This is generally needed if the current Oracle user connected is *not* the table owner.
2. You don't have SELECT privileges on the table. This is also generally needed if the current Oracle user connected is *not* the table owner.

You need to check both.