# CX_Oracle - import data from Oracle in a specific schema to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, oracle

when I check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781580/cx-oracle-import-data-from-oracle-to-pandas-dataframe?noredirect=1&lq=1), I don't understand why the solution is not working for me. I run the following code:

```
query = """SELECT* 
           FROM TRANSACTION
           """
df_ora = pd.read_sql(query, con=connection)
```

and get the error:
`DatabaseError: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

The database is organized in shemes, where Datenbasis is one scheme. So it looks like the following:
Database ---> Datenbasis -> Table --> TRANSACTION

what do I miss here, what do I have to specify?

I am connection as following:

```
db_connection_string = 'User/pw@server:port/Name'
con = cx_Oracle.connect(db_connection_string)
```

Comment: Are you connecting as `DATENBASIS` user?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, I added some explanation in my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to pick the right schema with the curser, the working code looks like:

```
db_connection_string = 'User/pw@server:port/Name'
con = cx_Oracle.connect(db_connection_string)
con.current_schema = 'DATENBASIS'
query = """SELECT* 
           FROM TRANSACTION
           """
df_ora = pd.read_sql(query, con=connection)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear:

1.The user you are connecting with has no privileges over the table.
2.The table does not exist at all.

```
db_connection_string = 'User/pw@server:port/Name'
```

You have to ask your DBA to grant select over the table to your user.

Besides, you would have to change:

```
query = """SELECT* 
           FROM TRANSACTION
           """
df_ora = pd.read_sql(query, con=connection)
```

for

```
query = """SELECT* 
           FROM SCHEMA_OWNER.TRANSACTION
           """
df_ora = pd.read_sql(query, con=connection)
```

Where schema_owner is the schema which owns the table. If you don't want to change this last part, you would need to create a synonym.

Comment: how do I know who is the SCHEMA_OWNER?

Comment: select owner from dba_tables where table_name = 'TRANSACTION'

Comment: if i run `cur.execute("SELECT owner from dba_tables where table_name= TRANSACTION")` I get the error: DatabaseError: ORA-00904

Comment: that is because your user has no privileges to the DBA_TABLES. You need to ask to your DBA for that

Comment: You can query from `ALL_TABLES` instead of `DBA_TABLES`

Comment: if the query on ALL_TABLES gives you 0 rows, it means your user has no privileges over the table. If the query works, replace schema_owner by the output of that query

Answer (score 0):

check if you can select from the table in SQL plus/ SQL developer, if not then the user id that you are using to connect to the DB does not have access to that table.

SELECT * FROM Datenbasis.TRANSACTION;