# Cx_oracle: To_date with variables in python

Tags: oracle, python-3.x, cursor, cx-oracle, to-date

I am trying to do this

```
startdate = "20160123"
enddate = "20160204"
cmd = "select identification_number from bug where submitted_date >= TO_DATE(:1,'dd-MON-yy') and submitted_date <= TO_DATE(:2,'dd-MON-yy')"
cursor.execute(cmd,(startdate,enddate))
```

I get an error

```
cursor.execute(cmd,(sdate,edate))
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

I saw previous threads regarding this error but nothing solved my problem

Comment: What does `:1` and `:2` mean here? The `to_date` function expects an `string` as first parameter.

Comment: @Utsav - they are just positional bind variable placeholders. (There's an explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33882805/266304)).

Comment: Ok. Thanks @AlexPoole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how `startdate` and `enddate` is translated to `:1` and `:2` but if it does, then the issue with date format. 
You are passing `YYYYMMDD` and you casting it as `DD-MON-YYYY` . Try to change it.
Also you are missing `from` clause.

And I'd used `between` clause instead.

```
select identification_number 
from <your_table>
where 
submitted_date between 
TO_DATE(:1,'YYYYMMDD') and TO_DATE(:2,'YYYYMMDD')
```

If this works, then use same date format in your code

```
startdate = "20160123"
enddate = "20160204"
cmd = "select identification_number from <your_table> where submitted_date between TO_DATE(:1,'YYYYMMDD') and TO_DATE(:2,'YYYYMMDD')"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed all the date formats to be of one specific form and it worked

Comment: How do you use `TO DATE()` inside an `executemany()` statement?