# Python: Calling queries from a file with variables

Tags: python, sql

I have a few queries in my python script which also use variables as parameters to retrieve data. 
`'''SELECT * FROM order_projections_daily WHERE days >= ''' + each + '''AND days < ''' + next_monday`

How can I store queries like this in a separate file and call it directly from there rather than cramming them in the code?

I have tried storing the queries in a file and calling them as a string but it doesn't work with variables. it works with:
`'''SELECT * FROM order_projections_daily'''`

This is a very simple query, I am using much more complicated queries in the real case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use parameterised strings—

```
'''SELECT * FROM order_projections_daily WHERE days >= %(start)s AND days < %(end)s'''
```

Later, when executing the query, build a params `dict` like this:

```
params = {'start': ..., 'end': ...}
```

These params should then be passed to the DBC driver function which will take care of inserting the parameters:

```
cursor.execute(query, params)
```

Note: Do *not* inject format strings into your query, you're liable to SQL injection that way.

Answer (score -5):

Use python string formatting.

In your separate file save query as below e.g:

```
query = "select * from my_persons where name = {name} and age = {age}"
```

In python file, format the query this way:

```
sql = query.format(name="jack", age=27)
```

You can save all your queries in a separate python file as string values and import all of them into your code anywhere. In my eg I am assuming query is saved in a separate python file.

Formatting your query

```
query='''SELECT * FROM order_projections_daily WHERE days >={each} AND days < {next_monday}
```

Format it as:

```
sql = query.format(each=each, next_monday=next_monday)
```

It's a good practice to use format method or % or maybe even join rather than using string concatenation as string concatenation creates intermediate string objects.

Ok so formatting is a bad idea then, have a look at this. Name binding in oracle https://stackoverflow.com/a/33882805/2196290

Comment: As with the other answer, **never** use string formatting with SQL queries to pass values. Always use your DB-API's or lib's placeholders.

Comment: Like name binding in oracle queries?