# Insert value variable into sql query from file.Python3

Tags: oracle, python-3.x, variables

I have the following Python code extract results to csv from an oracle database.

I have a txt file that contains a list of ID's
Example:

```
ID

ID124543

ID124544

ID124545
```

I want to read each ID from a file, insert it into a sql query as a variable.

`SQL="SELECT ID, FIELD1, FIELD2 FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE ID=variable"`

Help me, maybe someone solved this problem.
Tell me how to correctly associate variables with a sql query? I am using cx_Oracle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python cx\_Oracle bind variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868717/python-cx-oracle-bind-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following may work for you.  IIRC it came from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/prez-python-dataparsing-087750.html

```
import csv
import cx_Oracle

db = cx_Oracle.connect("hr", "hrpwd", "localhost/XE")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'")

reader = csv.reader(open("job_history.csv", "r"))
lines = []
for line in reader:
    lines.append(line)

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO job_his VALUES(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5)", lines)
db.commit()
```