# Oracle Bind Variable to_date parameter Error

Tags: python, sql, oracle, to-date, bind-variables

I am writing code which uses a Python script to execute a SQL (Oracle) statement, as shown below:

**PYTHON:**

```
with open(os.path.join(WORKING_PATH, "sql", "fetchCalendar.sql"), 'r') as 
    fetch_date = fetch.read()   
#(Some other code)
CD = timestamp_tostring(ACTUALDATE)
print("CD:", CD)
cnnSB.cursor.execute(fetch_date, CD)
```

**fetchCalendar.sql**

```
SELECT YEARNBR as yearnbr, QUARTERNBR as quarternbr, MONTHNBR as monthnbr, WEEKNBR as weeknbr
 FROM MFS_MFSCALENDAR
WHERE ACTUALDATE = TO_DATE(:CD, 'DD-MON-YY')
```

When I try running it with the following values, this is outputted:

> CD: 30-AUG-18
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "AHT_Init.py",
>   line 919, in 
>       init_load(data, end_of_week, cur, 3)   File "AHT_Init.py", line 644, in init_load
>       populate_rollup(modelid, test_data, train_data, rollup_cmd)   File "AHT_Init.py", line 684, in populate_rollup
>       cnnSB.cursor.execute(fetch_date, CD) cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

*(Emphasis on 'ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number')*

Naturally, I tried changing the variable names to no avail. I tried running the SQL code using Oracle SQL Developer (passing in *'01-JUN-18'*, including the single quotes, when prompted), and got this error:

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was
>   expected
>   01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
>   *Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
>              incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
>              required by the format model.
>   *Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
>              elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.

Though, when I swapped out the problematic line with the following:

```
WHERE ACTUALDATE = TO_DATE('01-JUN-18', 'DD-MON-YY');
```

the code worked as desired.
Can anybody walk me through what the issue might be, and how to solve it?
Thank you so much!

EDIT: I am aware of the missing semicolon in the fetchCalendar.sql code; this is necessary for how Python interacts with Oracle in this context. I added a semicolon when trying it on Oracle SQL Developer for testing purposes, but it should not cause an issue when removed for the .sql file.

Comment: What happens if you do `cnnSB.cursor.execute(fetch_date, CD=CD)`? Typically if you use named bind variables you should send them to the `execute()` function by name as well. This question has the details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868717/python-cx-oracle-bind-variables

Comment: What is fetchCalendar.sql? I don't know Python, but is it necessary to pass a string and convert it back to a date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:
In short, wrongtype error.

My code was passing in a datetime.date to a SQL to_date cast which was expecting a string.