# How to bind oracle sql procedure variable in python

Tags: python, sql, oracle, procedure

I have the below oracle sql procedure which is called by python using an sql file.
When I run the below procedure with actual value for account number, it gives as pop-up -> enter binds where I get to enter customer name value.

```sql
Declare  
   Accountnum   varchar2(200); 
   Startdtm     date;  
   Customername varchar2(200);
Begin  
   Accountnum := null; 
   Startdtm := null;
   Procedurename( Accountnum => ‘$$ACCNUM’, —- value is ‘19283-1’ Startdtm => Startdtm,  Customername => Customername);
  :Customername := Customername; —-value is ‘19283’
End;  
/ 
Commit;
```

This sql procedure file is called in python as below:

```py
def executeSQL(self, accnum, custname, sqlfile):
    f = open(sqlfile)
    fullSql = f.read()
    replacedSQL = fullSql.replace(“$$ACCNUM”, str(accnum))
    self.cur.callproc(“dbms_output.enable”)
    var1 = self.cur.var(str)
    self.cur.execute(replacedSQL, var1 = custname)
    self.cur.execute(“commit”)
```

After running this in python, the account num is getting replaced but for customer name it is printing the below error:

> ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number.

Could someone please explain where I went wrong.

Comment: You have curly quotes in the Python script. Please recopy with correct quotes. And put it in just a code block, not a quote block.

Comment: There must be a canonical question for this somewhere.

Comment: Is this binding a variable or concatenating a literal value? I don't know Python, but shouldn't it be something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33882805/230471

Answer (score 0):

Change `var1` to the name of the bind variable in the SQL text, i.e. to `Customername`:

```
self.cur.execute(replacedSQL, Customername = custname)
```

Overall I would prefer using a dictionary as shown in the comment link on your question.

Ideally you should also bind the account name instead of calling `replace`.  Otherwise you are still open to SQL injection attacks. And you also don't get the scalability benefits of statement reuse.

An unrelated tweak would be to call:

```
connection.commit()
```

instead of going through the overhead of sending a SQL COMMIT statement.

Or better would be to use autocommit.