# oracle : sql command does not complete correctly

Tags: python-3.x, database, oracle

I tried to update a table from xsls file, but the problem is that I have space when I parse the lines.

## Function:

```
def updateclientadress(nom, cnom, cplt_adr, adr, lieudit, cp, ville, numcli):
   #nom = str(nom)
   query = "update d_client set NOM = {}, CNOM = {}, CRUE = {}, RUE = {}, COMMUNE = {}, CODPOST = {}, VILLE = {} where NUMCLI = {}".format(nom, cnom, cplt_adr, adr, lieudit, cp, ville, numcli)
   print(query)
   cursorOracle.execute(query)
```

## Printing the query:

```
update d_client set NOM = STE SAS GIG, CNOM = nan, CRUE = Zone Industrielle de Pariacabo, RUE = Rue, COMMUNE = BP 81, CODPOST = nan, VILLE = nan where NUMCLI = 270
```

As you can see, there are spaces in "NOM", "CRUE", so the oracle doesn't accept the update status,

## The Error:

```
error:ORA-00933: la commande SQL ne se termine pas correctement
```

*Note that the variable is extracted from an excel file. And the goal is to parse the 200k lines to update the database.*

Comment: Please only use `code` formatting for code.  If you want to divide your problem into segments use different formatting options.

Comment: You aren't putting quotes around the variable values (`set NOM = '{}'`); but you [should be using bind variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33882805/266304) rather than embedding the values in the query string.

Comment: @AlexPoole, if i use the '{}', the script gonna take nan values as string, and i am gonna have 'Nan' value instead of empty

Comment: Well you would only do that for string values... but like I (and MTO) already said you shouldn't be doing this at all, you should be using bind variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NEVER** use string concatenation (or template strings) to build queries; that is how you introduce SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Instead, you should use a parameterised query and bind variables:

```python
def updateclientadress(nom, cnom, cplt_adr, adr, lieudit, cp, ville, numcli):
   query = "update d_client set NOM = :1, CNOM = :2, CRUE = :3, RUE = :4, COMMUNE = :5, CODPOST = :6, VILLE = :7 where NUMCLI = :8"
   cursorOracle.execute(query, [nom, cnom, cplt_adr, adr, lieudit, cp, ville, numcli])
```